# List all my comments made on GitHub, newest first

Tags: github, navigation

Lichess has this feature, [here an example](https://lichess.org/forum/search?text=user%3Adboing). We get a list of the comments a user made, newest first. Each entry is a link, followed by the first few lines of the comment.

Does GitHub have something like this?

Edit: searching for `commenter:username` is not what I want. It only shows the first PR comment I made, but not further comments I made in that PR, no matter which sorting I choose.